# Vegafusion No module named 'vl_convert' error python

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, modulenotfounderror

I am using vegafusion with altair and python to display a chart that won't show because of the max rows limit, but I have installed vegafusion and imported and enabled it.

When I go to run the visualisation, I get this error

```
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vegafusion\compilers.py in vl_convert_compiler(vegalite_spec)
     16     try:
---> 17         import vl_convert as vlc
     18     except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vl_convert'
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] and package versions

Answer (score 0):

The [VegaFusion mime renderer](https://vegafusion.io/mime_renderer.html) requires the [vl-convert-python](https://github.com/vega/vl-convert) package. This comes along automatically if you install VegaFusion with:

```
pip install -U "vegafusion[embed]"
```

But you can also install it separately with:

```bash
pip install -U vl-convert-python
```

Hope that helps!